# Existe algum padrão para Require, Include no PHP?

Tags: php, funções, arquivo-header

Olá, estou **iniciando** no PHP e trabalhando em alguns projetos no estágio ao mesmo tempo, então estou aprendendo e resolvendo ao mesmo tempo, percebi que acabo utilizando muitos includes e includes_once eventualmente acaba ocorrendo problemas, algo que com o entendimento sobre a diferença entre eles pude diminuir, entretanto **eu gostaria de saber se existe um padrão?**

Pois eu tive uma ideia que seria a criação de um *header* com diversas funções e dentro dessas funções estariam os includes, requires com as páginas necessárias para o funcionamento da página atual.

Claro tentando deixar essas funções **o mais generalizadas** o possível, pois assim eu poderia utilizar uma função para diversas páginas.

Comment: A diferença entre `include` e `require` é a forma como um erro é tratado. require produz um erro `E_COMPILE_ERROR` , o que encerra a execução do script. O `include` apenas produz um `warning` que pode ser "abafado" com @

Comment: A minha pergunta não foi essa amigo, eu a coloquei em negrito, inclusive fecharam a minha pergunta, mas ela não é aquela, eu não quero saber para o que serve e suas diferenças e sim se há alguma maneira inteligente ou um padrão a ser usado, por isso eu falei na criação de um Header, colocando-as em funções para e dando require apenas no arquivo de funções e utilizando a melhor função para a página/script atual. Obrigado pela resposta mas não é essa a minha pergunta.